# WFS-T on postgis view using geoserver

Tags: gis, postgis, geoserver

We are developing a GIS solution using a Postgis database and GeoServer for WMS Image rendering and WFS queries,We use sql views to create geoserver layers because manipulating a view for us in easier than using direct tables because our layers are dynamic,a user can import a layer (ex: a shape file or a GeoJSON file) to our database and can insert,update or remove a feature from a web interface made using lefleat.WFS read queries like describeFeatureType works fine,but now we want to enable WFS-T to our layers hosted on geoserver so users can edit them from QGIS for exemple.
I had made a lot of research on the web to do so but none of the solutions worked me for making WFS-T works with a postgis view,I have already created a metadata table "pk_metadata_table" on my database and reference it from my PostGIS DataStore,i also applied rules to my POSTGIS view so i can insert ,edit and delete on it,in reality it works fine with pgadmin when i try for exemple to insert in a view but when a try WFS-T request on a layer, Geoserver tell me that the layer is "read only" so any one could make things work  for WFS-T on  a postgis (not oracle please) View in the past can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved it by setting Geoserver CATALOG MODE, under Data Security tab (left hand side) as CHALLENGE MODE. hope it result's